# WebView em 2º plano é possível?

Tags: android, webview

Bom dia amigos, estou criando um app muito simples, ele carrega uma url na webview (url do site da getrak rastreamento) pois quando há uma ocorrência a página toca um som. Meu app funciona perfeitamente, só que após eu desligar a tela (2minutos +/-) a webview para. Como posso fazer para que a webview fique atualizando essa URL mesmo quando eu sair do app???

Ja tentei de tudo e não deu jeito, fiz um Service com BroadcastReceiver, AlarmManager e tal mas mesmo assim ela não mantém o funcionamento

```
package com.atualizador.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class myBackgroundProcess extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MainActivity.atualizar.callOnClick();
    }

}
```

atualizar é um botão que tem esse código:

```
atualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
                repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                sistema.loadUrl("https://sistema.getrak.com/semprealerta/msumario/index/index");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 0, 4000);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala Jefferson, beleza?

Cara, pra ser sincero eu nunca vi um caso de webview rodando em background e nem acho que essa seja a melhor abordagem.


Por alguns motivos:

- A intenção da webview é justamente mostrar algo na UI;
- Webview é um componente utilizado para abrir links externos e navegação externa;
- O **S.O.** pode encerrar e "capar" recursos da sua aplicação sempre que quiser para liberar memória;

O que eu poderia recomendar é você utilizar uma PeriodicWorkRequest (WorkManager) ou AlarmManager com alarme repetitivo disparando uma função que sincronize com seu backend e faça com que o aplicativo toque o som se necessário.


Existem várias abordagens pra fazer isso de forma nativa, você decide! As ferramentas (combinadas) que podem resolver seu problema são:

- [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms);
- [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver);
- [WorkManager](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006);
- [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=pt-br).

Não estou me aprofundando, pois vi que você já implementou alguns deles.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços ;)